# validator getting lost because of FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, validation, flutter-dependencies, customvalidator

I have a screen that has a static form and then I add some dynamic fields that come from an API. then each field has a validator, but for the dynamic fields I did it with a FutureBuilder, then after I added the FutureBuilder the validators only work for the dynamic fields and not for the static ones

Here is my static fields:

```
      CampoUserSenha(
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                readOnly: false,
                validator: (val) => combine([
                  () => isNotEmpty(val),
                  () => validaNome(
                        val,
                      ),
                ]),
                controller: _nomeController,
                inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[a-zA-Z ]"))
                ],
                prefixIcon: const Icon(
                  Icons.account_circle,
                  color: roxoPadrao,
                ),
                labelText: 'Nome completo',
                obscureText: false,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              CampoUserSenha(
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                readOnly: false,
                inputFormatters: [
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                ],
                controller: phoneController,
                prefixIcon: const Icon(
                  Icons.phone,
                  color: roxoPadrao,
                ),
                labelText: 'Numero de contato',
                keyboardType:  TextInputType.number,
                obscureText: false,
              ),
```

here my FutureBuilder:

```
         FutureBuilder<List<FormulariosModel>>(
                future: FormulariosHttp().formulariosEmpresa(context),
                builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<List<FormulariosModel>> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    List<FormulariosModel> formularios = snapshot.data!;
                    List<Widget> campos = [];

                    Map<String, Widget Function(BuildContext, FormulariosModel)>
                        fieldTypeMap = {
                      '5': checkBox,
                      'T': (context, formulario) {
                        if (formulario.formatacao == '4') {
                          return campoData(context, formulario);
                        } else if (formulario.originalFormat == 'S') {
                          return campoMascaraDinamica(context, formulario);
                        } else if (formulario.formatacao == '5') {
                          return campoDataHora(context, formulario);
                        } else if (formulario.originalFormat == '6') {
                          return campoHora(context, formulario);
                        } else if (formulario.formatacao == '9') {
                          return campoIp(context, formulario);
                        } else if (formulario.formatacao == 'M') {
                          return campoMoeda(context, formulario);
                        } else if (formulario.formatacao == 'I') {
                          return campoNumeroInteiro(context, formulario);
                        } else if (formulario.formatacao == null) {
                          return campoTextoPuro(context, formulario);
                        }
                        return campoCpf(context, formulario);
                      },
                      'S': campoLista,
                      'R': campoRadio,
                      '6': campoMultiplaSelecoes,
                      'L': campoAreaDeTexto,
                      // Adicione mais mapeamentos aqui conforme necessário
                    };

                    for (FormulariosModel formulario in formularios) {
                      if (fieldTypeMap.containsKey(formulario.type)) {
                        campos.add(fieldTypeMap[formulario.type]!(
                            context, formulario));
                      }
                    }
                    return Column(
                      children: campos.map((campo) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                          child: campo,
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    );
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                  } else {
                    return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }
                },
              ),
```

And my method that I call to create an account:

```
  criarConta([FormulariosModel? formulario]) async {
    final nome = _nomeController.text;
    final telefone = phoneController.text;
    final email = _emailController.text;
    final senha = passwordController.text;
    final confirmaSenha = passwordConfirmController.text;
    String cpf = _cpfController.text;
    bool formIsValid = formKey.currentState!.validate();

    if (formulario?.requireed == true && !isChecked) {
      FlushBarComponente.mostrar(context, 'Preencha os campos obrigatórios',
          Icons.warning_amber, vermelhoPadrao);
      return;
    }



    if (formIsValid && _validaCPF(context, cpf) &&
        _validaNomeEmail(context, nome, email, senha, confirmaSenha) == true) {
      var resposta = await CriarContaHttp()
          .criarConta(nome, telefone, email, senha, context);
      if (resposta != null) {
        if (resposta.requireValidation == true) {
          Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, Routes.validaEmail);
          });
        } else if (resposta.wait == true) {
          Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, Routes.waitScreen);
          });
        } else if (resposta.error == true) {
          FlushBarComponente.mostrar(
              context, resposta.message, Icons.warning_amber, vermelhoPadrao);
        }
      } else {
        FlushBarComponente.mostrar(context, 'Erro ao criar conta',
            Icons.warning_amber, vermelhoPadrao);
      }
    }
  }
```

obs: I debugged it and it is not arriving in the validator, and when I removed the FutureBuilder it returned the noraml message which is the one that appears below the field in red

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what's causing your problem but I notice one mistake. In your `FutureBuilder` you have

```
future: FormulariosHttp().formulariosEmpresa(context),
```

But this makes it that it calls the future again on every rebuild. What you'd want to do have something like this in the state

```
  late Future myFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myFuture = FormulariosHttp().formulariosEmpresa(context);
  }
```

and then use

```
future: myFuture,
```

in the `FutureBuilder`

Comment: the main problem was not resolved but thanks for your attention in pointing out the error, I have already changed it here